# Tag description doesn't show hyperlink

Tags: customization

I have added HTML code into my TAG description box, but for some reason the output doesn't display the required results.

I have even tried to add HREF tag manually into this box, but no hyperlinks are visible. The code contains tag_description();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put HTML in taxonomy descriptions, but you can use a plugin such as http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/allow-html-in-category-descriptions/ to enable that functionality.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, after several tries, I have figured out the plugin no longer works on WordPress 3.4.1 version. Is there anything else that I could use? (I am trying out other plugins right now)

Comment: If you can't find a plugin you could try making one yourself. I don't see why (on quick glance) that plugin wouldn't work. It simply removes the `wp_filter_kses` filter that turns off the HTML stripping: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/allow-html-in-category-descriptions/trunk/html-in-category-descriptions.php

Comment: I disabled RICH TEXT TAGS plugin and re-enabled the plugin you mentioned... and yes, it works perfectly. I can add HTML codes in the box now. I have spent 3 hours trying to understand all these stuffs, and finally you solved the problem in 10 minutes! Thanks developdaly! You are the man...

Answer (score 1):

**You can simply remove the filters - *( functions.php )***

```
// Before saving into database
remove_filter( 'pre_term_description', 'wp_filter_kses' );

// Before displaying data 
remove_filter( 'term_description', 'wp_kses_data'     );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Amit! Right now I am using a plugin that does exactly what you have mentioned! This will be handy though.